# why does webpack loader on django and vuejs shows TypeError when using render bundle?

Tags: django, vue.js

Im trying to work with Django and vuejs using the webpack loader, however I'm running into this template error, Here is the full traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'webpack_loader',
 'topics']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/grollier/Projects/Python/bethel/bethel_site/templates/index.html, error at line 21
   **string indices must be integers**
   11 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
   12 :     </head>
   13 :     <body>
   14 :         <noscript>
   15 :             <Strong>We're sorry but frontend doesn't work properly without JavaScript enable. Please enable it to continue.</Strong>
   16 :         </noscript>
   17 :         <div id="app">
   18 :             <app></app>
   19 :         </div>
   20 : 
   21 :          {% render_bundle 'app' %} 
   22 : 
   23 :         <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
   24 :     </body>
   25 : </html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webpack_loader/templatetags/webpack_loader.py", line 12, in render_bundle
    tags = utils.get_as_tags(bundle_name, extension=extension, config=config, attrs=attrs)
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webpack_loader/utils.py", line 64, in get_as_tags
    for chunk in bundle:
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webpack_loader/loader.py", line 43, in filter_chunks
    for regex in self.config['ignores'])
  File "/home/grollier/anaconda3/envs/bethel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webpack_loader/loader.py", line 43, in <genexpr>
    for regex in self.config['ignores'])

**Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: string indices must be integers**
```

here is my vue.config.js file:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker")

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
  outputDir: '.dist/',

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization
        .splitChunks(false)

    config
        .plugin('BundleTracker')
        .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: '../webpack-stats.json'}])

    config.resolve.alias
        .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

    config.devServer
        .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
        .host('0.0.0.0')
        .port(8080)
        .hotOnly(true)
        .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
        .https(false)
        .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
  },
  pages: {
    app: 'src/main.js'
  },
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

and if it helps here is my setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
**TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
FRONTEND_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend')**


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'This-one-is-a-secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader',
    'topics'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bethel_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bethel_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

**# Webpack configuration thru webpack_loader
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'webpack_bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot.update.js', r'.+\.map'],
        'LOADER_CLASS': 'webpack_loader.loader.WebpackLoader'
    }**
}
```

so Im not sure why I'm running into this TypeError since I followed a tutorial and read the documentation on webpackloader and culdn't find where is the error or where should a correct so it receives the correct type whenever it tries to render the bundle. Any help will be aprecciated. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I know the answer is a little late, but I've just had the same issue.

You most likely have the latest version of `webpack-bundle-tracker` installed, which is currently incompatible with the the latest version of `django-webpack-loader`.

`webpack-bundle-tracker` is the one that is on alpha release, so you'll need to downgrade that one to v0.4.3. To do this just run:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
```

You may need to delete your old `webpack-stats.json` file to trigger the building of a new one.

Everything should work fine then :) For a fuller discussion you can see this issue:
https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/issues/227

Comment: Thanks @tim-mccurrach, I found the **issue topic** on github and I've already downgraded webpack-bundle-tracker and its working great.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from  version  django-webpack-loader.

Try to downgrade version. django and webpack

django

```
pip uninstall django-webpack-loader
pip install django-webpack-loader==0.7.0
```

webpack

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
```

You may need to delete your old webpack-stats.json